# Garage is beining demolished how do i disconnect electric line from my house

Tags: electrical

An Electic line runs from house to garage. I need to diconnect before demolished.

Comment: How about some pictures of it and the panels it goes into. It's probably on th load side of the meter so the power company won't do it.  Is it an overgead line or an underground line?

Comment: Do you have a breaker at the main panel? If you're comfortable inside a panel, you can disconnect there. If you aren't comfortable with (potentially) lethal electricity, get a pro to do it.

Comment: A good question is more than a tweet.  Every house is different.  Where is the electric meter?  You'll need to [edit] to add some details, preferably photos, or else we won't be able to help you.  If you need to switch devices to add photos, then [register your account](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) to an email, Facebook etc. so the system knows you're the same person on the different devices.

Comment: One might suspect that whomever is demolishing the garage has a vested interest in disconnecting it as well…

Answer (score 2):

You (or someone you hire - an electrician, at least for the second step, not just any random worker) needs to:

1. Turn off the power to the garage power line connection - which should be easy if the power meter is at the house, and the house feeds power to the garage. In the opposite situation (meter at Garage, house powered from garage) you'll need to have the service relocated and get the utility involved. That will be far more complicated and expensive to get done.
2. Remove the wires from the turned-off breaker (or removed fuse) that was powering the garage.
3. Continue to remove wires where they exit the house and connect to the garage, above or below ground, as applicable.